# Bounded Type Parameter not allowing access to methods of appropriate objects

Tags: java, generics, interface, libgdx

I have a `GameWorld` class where I `update` and `render` most of my game. In this class I need a method that removes objects that go off the screen bounds. Further, because most of my game objects are stored in `ArrayLists`'s I need to make a generic method which can do this job for multiple types of objects. This said I am aware that in order for this to work with generics those "objects" must be related to each other: either by inheritance or interfaces. This said here is what I tried:

I have an interface called `WorldEntities` which broadly reflects on what each entity in the game should do. Here it is:

```
public interface WorldEntities {
    void update(float delta, GameWorld game);
    void render(SpriteBatch batch);
    Vector2 getPosition();
    Rectangle getBounds();
}
```

Using this interface I tried creating a generic method that can remove any object that goes off the screen bounds. Here is my attempt:

```
public <T extends WorldEntities> void deleteOffScreenObjects(ArrayList<T> objectList){
     Iterator itr = objectList.iterator();
     while (itr.hasNext()){
         if(itr.next().getPosition().y < -AssetLoader.cloud.getHeight()){
            itr.remove();
         }
     }
}
```

This method however has a problem at `itr.next().getPosition().y` saying that `Cannot resolve method getPosition()`.

At first I was thinking that the first thing that comes after the `extends` should be a normal class. From what I read this is true but only if you have bounded parameters with interfaces and classes, so this couldn't be the problem. (From the documentation: ["If one of the bounds is a class, it must be specified first."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html))

NOTE: `-AssetLoader.cloud.getHeight()` is just a constant. I will change it after I get this problem sorted out.

So my question is: Why can't I access `getPosition()` even though any parameter that gets passed in to `deleteOffScreenObjects` implements an interface which ensures that this method is available and implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) for the Iterator declaration which has no information about the types stored in the `List`

```
Iterator<T> iterator = objectList.iterator();
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I did not catch that after reading so many articles!

Answer (score 2):

You need to type the iterator as well...

```
Iterator itr = objectList.iterator();
```

Becomes

```
Iterator<T> itr = objectList.iterator();
```

That way, when you call `.next()` on your `Iterator<T>` you will get back an object of Type `T` instead of just an `Object` (which is the default if you don't explicitly type your iterator).

Comment: Yeah, and that makes sense too.